# contentOffset Changes With Unknown Reason

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

In my application there is a UITabBarController and UIViewControllers in tab pages. Some View Controllers contains UIScrollView that used for paging. I am changing contentOffset regarding the business logic on ViewController.

Strange thing is, after changed contentOffset (for example current value (660,0)) and press another tab button, another view controller opens normally. But if press previous tab bar i see white screen. When i dig into details i saw contentOffset changed to weird point (1000,0).

I couldn't understand why and couldn't find a way to fix. Also there is nothing about changing  offset at viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad methods.